# Is there any tool for making decision trees and then converting theme into JSON/XML format?

Tags: gratis, json, xml, modeling, classification

I'm looking for a free desktop tool that offer you the possibility to create decision/classification tree and then export that tree into a known format, ideally JSON or XML.
I'd like to add that actually i'll be using this tool for software testing, so the nodes of the tree will act like test cases of a particular functionality.